# Return JSON from Express error handling middleware instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am having a bit of an issue returning a JSON response from my Express handling middleware. Currently, I am getting an HTML error page in Postman. On my actual client, I only return a `500 error` from the `fetch` request in the console. The JSON data that should be the error message does not come through as anticipated.

Here is my error handling function. It simply passes the error as a JSON response back to the client. Anytime `next(some_error)` is called in my controller routes, Express pipes them through this error handling function:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

exports.errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  res.status(500).json({ err });
};

module.exports = router;
```

Here is a portion of the controller route that I am throwing an intentional error in to test the error handling middleware:

```
   if (isMatch) {
      const payload = { id: user._id };

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        { expiresIn: 900000 },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) {
            const error = new Error(JWT_FAILED);
            error.httpStatusCode = 400;
            return next(error);
          }
          payload.token = `Bearer ${token}`;
          return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            accountant: payload
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      const error = new Error(PASSWORD_INCORRECT);
      error.genericError =
        'The provided password did not match the database.';
      error.httpStatusCode = 400;
      return next(error);
    }
```

This is the page I am getting in response for reference:

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I usually don't have an issue sending a JSON response back from Express. I have a hunch the errors handled by Express require an extra step somewhere to not default to returning as HTML and not JSON.

Comment: Where is your `errorHandler` actually attached to the `app`?

Comment: below the routes in my `server.js`: It looks like: `app.use(errorHandler);`. I should of mentioned that initially but my error handler is working (albeit not returning JSON) so I didn't think to include that.

Comment: One thing to note is that your `res.setHeader()` call is superfluous. The [`res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) method already sets the correct Content-Type on the response. Do you have any other error-handling middleware before your `errorHandler`? I'd also add a `console.log()` in your `errorHandler`, preferably with a `Date` inserted, so you can see exactly when (or when not) it is being called.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I did have another error handling middleware used to log out bad endpoint requests in my terminal. I have commented that out to see if that was causing an issue and it didn't have any effect. I used `res.setHeader()` in a vain attempt to try and make it work, removed it and left `res.json()` and is still returning an HTML page.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no worries, all things considered and I have definitely done that. But I am using Nodemon so it's handling that for me.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, given this information, but I do suggest adding `console.log()` to each of the relevant areas in your pipeline to verify the assumptions you've made so far. I've experienced several bugs that I wasn't able to fix until I realized that some of my implicit assumptions about what the code was doing were wrong.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no worries, I appreciate the help regardless.

Comment: How are you including that error module? Where is `errorHandler` in `app.use(errorHandler)` coming from?

Comment: @ChrisG `errorHandler` comes from a middleware directory in my app. `app.use(errorHandler)` is located in my root `server.js` file. I did however solve the issue below and it was due to how I was exporting my `errorHandler` function and incorrectly thinking that I had to export it with `router`.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue. I removed `router` and added `module.exports = errorHandler` and this resolved the issue. Express was not calling my `errorHandler` middleware function. It was just seeing a `next(some_error)` in my controller routes and then returning the error it's default way. I assumed my `errorHandler` function was returning this when in fact, my function was never even called.

This is the updated error handling middleware:

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ err: 'and error' });
};

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

This now sends back JSON. Phewwww.

Comment: So this has really nothing to to with JSON, or express, or error handling, or anything your title/question suggests. This was all about understanding how `require()` works, essentially. Which makes this Q&A a duplicate, and pretty useless without heavily editing it. I'd delete this answer, then the question, tbh.

Comment: They say hindsight is 20/20 but I can't believe I overlooked that. Good find.

Comment: @ChrisG sure, mark it as a duplicate. That doesn't require the question or answer to be deleted. They can do that at their own discretion, if they wish. Duplicate questions _can_ still help the site, and this is a good example of a well-written question and answer. OP was responsive to feedback, provided enough information to reproduce the problem, etc. Honestly I don't understand the mentality that the question has to be deleted just because the same problem has been solved before...

Comment: @ChrisG if only I could of written the title when I actually knew what the issue was. Someone else could make the same mistake because the `Express` docs are dry in explanation when it comes to defining exported error handling middleware functions. I assumed I needed to export the error handling middleware function with `router`, wasn't the case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm not criticizing OP's behavior or claiming this is a bad question or answer. I'm saying that given how this website is supposed to work, this question should be edited heavily in order to be useful to future readers.

Comment: @maison.m Sorry, I don't mean to be rude in any way. Of course you didn't realize what the actual issue was when you posted this; I'm not saying this is your fault or anything like that (although explaining how node modules work is not the job of the express docs). All I'm saying is that this question should be edited according to what turned out to be the actual issue.

Comment: @maison.m that's not the responsibility of express documentation to teach conventions for modularization best practices. It's not "dry", it's just documenting only what's directly relevant to the framework. If you are unsure of conventions for writing modules, consult the Node.js documentation itself.